# Android: can't find device in developer console

Tags: android, device, publish

Using the Google Play Developer Console I can't find the `SM-N9005 (Samsung Galaxy Note 3)` in supported devices.

In `"all devices"`, `"supported"`, `"unsupported"` and `"manually excluded"` I can't find `SM-N9005`...

but there are a lot of Galaxy Note 3.

If I search for my app in the Google Play Store i can see that the SM-N9005 is not supported.
There's no particular restriction in the manifest...other Galaxy Note 3 are well supported.
Does anyone can help me?
Regards

Comment: Have you written some lines of code in your Manifest.xml about which device will be supported or not?

Comment: No...others Galaxy Note 3 are supported correctly...this is strange! I exclude a manifest problem because if there is some restriction in the code I must see SM-N9005 in the "unsupported devices".

Comment: It looks like that the specific device "SM-N9005" isn't supported by the store :D, but this makes no sence.. can you install other apps from the store? Or does it say "not supported" too?

Comment: I can install all the app normally available on the Google Play Store.
It isn't a problem relative to mine SM-N9005...other SM-N9005 have the some problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Play Developer Console the SM-N9005 (Galaxy Note 3) is mapped as hlte (Samsung Galaxy Note 3 Duos).

This is a strange matching because the SM-N9005 isn't a dual sim device, but the Galaxy Note 3 Duos has two sim.

> So the answer is: if you want to grant access to your app from all Galaxy Note 3 you have to include also the Galaxy Note 3 Duos devices in "supported devices".

Thanks all for your answers

Comment: In my case it is not valid anymore, I can not see both Galaxy Note 3 Duos and SM-N9005. U got any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> Can't find device in developer console

The most obvious answer to point out is:

For Microsoft Windows platform, have you installed Samsung universal USB drivers for mobile devices for Windows? If not, do this first.

For Linux, install similar drivers.

See this [link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=11633550#post11633550) from XDA forum about getting the USB drivers for your device.

After the drivers are installed, try the following ADB commands in succession in DOS prompt or Linux shell.

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
adb devices
```

The last command will show your device.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you have install/update the Google usb driver from sdk manager extras. Will allow you to have any types of android device usb drivers.
Also try to restart the adb

Comment: I'm talking about Google Play Console...not debub/usb on device