# Samsung Galaxy Note 3 SM-N9005 google play console device catalog

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, samsung-mobile, google-play-console

Been trying to find out why Samsung Galaxy Note 3 is not supported by my app and it doesn't show in "All Devices" in "Device Catalog" in Google Play Console.

There are articles saying it could be because Google Play Services is not working or the device catalog list it wrongly.

Not really sure where the fault is cause Google Play console also don't provide specific details why a device is supported.

Anyone got problems like this for Galaxy Note 3 SM-N9005? 
And how to provide a fix (or any articles will do)?

This is the details for the Note 3 
[image]

This is the manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.herdhr.operationapp_dev"
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<!-- optional permission -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />

<!-- GCM -->
<permission
    android:name="com.herdhr.operationapp_dev.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.herdhr.operationapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS"/> -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<!--
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
-->
<application
    android:name=".classes.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:persistent="true"

    android:largeHeap="true"
    >

    <!--
        some codes here
    -->

</application>
```

ref:
[Android: can't find device in developer console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22192774/android-cant-find-device-in-developer-console/22221226#22221226)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey for those who encounter this issue this is what I concluded.

Answer: My app will not support all Samsung Note 3 models.

Why:
Samsung Note 3 SM-N9005 has a known issue and there is no official fix from manufacturers. The issue is on Google Play Services and affects the Play Store functionality to download apps.

ref:
 https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/sTfOQ73GyKo